# For a list of pairs, how can I reference the second elements that are the same to then sort the first?

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of tuples, each containing a character and an integer, e.g.

```
tuple_list = [('b', 7), ('a', 3), ('c', 3), ('d', 9), ('e', 3)]
```

How can I write a condition so that for each tuple with he same number, I sort them alphabetically?

I have tried something like:

```
for i in range(len(tuple_list)): 
    if any(tuple_list[I] == tuple_list[I+1:]: 
        ....
        sorted(tuple_list,key=lambda x:x[0])
```

My idea in the ... is to transfer the tuples into another list, sort them then put them back again, but surely there's a way to achieve this in-place? `My issue is referencing all of the tuples with the same numbers- how can I do this?`

Because if I have this then it is easy to sort it. Thanks

Expected output: `[('d', 9), ('b', 7), ('a', 3), ('c', 3),('e', 3)]`

Comment: "so that for each tuple with he same number, I sort them alphabetically?" - Could you provide your exact expected output in order to make that perfectly clear?

Comment: "tuples with two elements each" are called "pairs". Using the simple word "pair" will make the title of your post both shorter, and easier to read and understand at a glance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) which has an argument `key` which is a function that returns a value and `sorted` sorts after that value. In your case we need a function that returns first  the integer than the character, and sorts each tuple according to that - we can use the function `lambda x : (x[1],x[0])` since it returns the (integer,character) for each tuple i.e first sorts after integer, then after character

```py
tuple_list = [('b', 3), ('c', 2), ('a', 2), ('d', 1), ('e', 1)]
sorted_list = sorted(tuple_list, key = lambda x: (x[1],x[0]))

#[('d', 1), ('e', 1), ('a', 2), ('c', 2), ('b', 3)]
```

Comment: "so that for each tuple with he same number, I sort them alphabetically" - there is nothing in your code that guarantees that. The output is sorted only because the input already was.

Comment: My bad - forgot to sort after the character aswell. Have editted it to sort after a tuple

Comment: Hi CutePoison, but I want to first sort by greatest number, then alphabetically. Doesn't this run into the issue, where for the former 'reverse=True' and for the latter 'reverse=False'.

Comment: CutePoison, I believe your code only sorts one way- is there a way to do reverse=True then reverse=False?

Comment: I can see there's several questions of that exactly problem at SO - it seems like the only way is to double sort i.e call `sorted` with reverse=True and then again with reverse=False. Other than that you can reverse it on the integers by setting `key = lambda x: (-x[1],x[0])` (note the "-" infront of the number).

Comment: Thanks CutePoison, but I am still having issues even if I do 2 sorts. With the first sort that is easy. However, how can I sort the second time? Because in the second sort I only want to sort the pairs that have the same integer value.

Comment: This is important, because if we simply sort first by number, then alphabetically, this WILL NOT produce the same answer as what I need, as stated in y comment above

Comment: Does it have to be "native python" or are you allowed to use other libraries e.g `pandas`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort by multiple keys like in this case you can use something like this:

```py
tuple_list = [('b', 3), ('a', 2), ('c', 2), ('d', 1), ('e', 1), ('a', 1), ('g', 1), ('b', 1)]

a = sorted(tuple_list, key=lambda tpl: (tpl[1], tpl[0]))

print(a)
```

(I added a few more items to the list to show that it actually also sorts it alphabetically too)

Not entirely sure how it works but I guess what happens is that it goes through the list and takes each list item (tuple) as an argument then it is possible to put the items in tuple in the lambda function in order to be sorted in so first sort the numbers (`tpl[1]`) then the characters (`tpl[0]`)

Comment: Hi Matiiss, there is a small issue with this, as I want to first sort the tuples by descending number order, and then alphabetically. So the 'reverse=True' then 'reverse=False'- but your code does both 'reverse=False'

Comment: @iffhhf straight from the docs you can take a look a this: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sort-stability-and-complex-sorts, specifically at the function `multisort()` example, I will probably write an example in a while but so far look at this

Comment: @iffhhf Use `key=lambda pair: (-pair[1], pair[0])` to "manually" reverse the order by using the opposite of the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way but you can do it by sorting twice. e.g.

```
tuple_list = [('b', 3), ('a', 2), ('c', 2), ('d', 1), ('e', 1), ('a', 1)]
sorted_list = sorted(
    sorted(tuple_list, key=lambda x: x[0]), key=lambda x: x[1])
print(sorted_list)
```

The output from this will be:-

[('a', 1), ('d', 1), ('e', 1), ('a', 2), ('c', 2), ('b', 3)]

Comment: As stated in the two answers below, you can avoid this by making lambda return a tuple `(x[1],x[0])` instead of running it twice

Comment: You're right. I said there might be a better way

Comment: Agreed - It was just an information for people who sees your answer

Comment: CutePoison, please see my comment to your answer regarding the 'reverse=True'